# Make BitBucket Server Recognize Readme by Different Name

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server, readme

Using BitBucket Server, when viewing a folder in a repository that contains a README file, the contents of that file are automatically displayed on screen. It seems to automatically detect files names, for instance, "README.txt" or "README.md". However, it appears to require that the filename match must be exact. (except for the file extension) For instance, "_README.txt" is not automatically displayed.

Is there a way to change the parsing logic for BitBucket Server for which file(s) are automatically detected and displayed? More specifically, I'd like it to detect and display files named either "README" or "_README".

The reason for adding the underscore is it ensures that, when browsing the source code in Windows File Explorer or similar, sorting files alphabetically will (usually) show the "_README" first, making it easier to notice/find.